# Checking String parameters corresponding to field names

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm heavily using `Java.lang.Class.getField()` method which requires a `String` variable as an argument. The problem I'm facing is when I change field names, that `getField()` refers to, Eclipse doesn't warn me that argument points nowhere (since it's `String`) and I end up having methods working improperly unnoticed.

So far I can see two ways out. It's either using `try-catch` blocks around every `getField()` call and running application to see what will be the next line to throw an exception. Fix it and watch out for the next exception. Or it's using Find/Replace feature every time I change a field name to manually look for the String value and replace it. Is there a more friendly (i.e. automatic) way to update String parameters in such cases?

Maybe there's a method (which I fail to find) that accepts a full field path as a non-String argument and returns a `Field` object? Something like `turnToFieldObject(car.speed)` returning `Field` object corresponding to `speed` field so that Eclipse would automatically check if there's such a field `car.speed`.

**PS**

First of all, thank you for your replies.

I can see that a lot of you, guys, suggest that I'm using reflection too much. That's why I feel I need to add extra explanation and would be glad to hear suggestions as well.

I'm doing a research about modeling social evolution and I need the entities to evolve new features that they don't have at the start. And it seemed to me that adding new fields to represent some evolutional changes is better understanding wise than adding new elements to arrays or collections. And the task suggests I shouldn't be able to know what feature will be evolved. That's why I rely so heavily on reflection.

Comment: This is something you should check using unit/integration tests

Comment: It seems a little code smell that you are using reflection so much; maybe you ought to reconsider the design? Like using getters and setters, which are also much faster then using reflection.

Comment: "And it seemed to me that adding new fields to represent some evolutional changes is better understanding wise than adding new elements to arrays or collections" - a `Map` would be a MUCH more flexible solution. Adding new fields at runtime is problematic and it pretty much makes it nearly impossible to make sensible interfaces. I'll update my answer with alternative solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such method. You pass a reference (if it's an object) or value (if it's primitive); all data about the variables that they were originally assigned to is not available at runtime.

This is the huge downside of using reflection, and if you're "heavily" using this feature in such way, you're probably doing something wrong. Why not access the field directly, using getters and setters?

Don't get me wrong, reflection has its uses (for example, when you want to scan for fields with certain annotations and inject their values), but if you're referencing fields or methods by their name using a simple string, you could just as well access fields or methods directly. It implies that you know the field beforehand. If it's private, there is probably a reason why it's encapsulated. You're losing the content assist and refactoring possibilities by overusing reflection.

If you're *modeling social evolution*, I'd go with a more flexible solution. Adding new fields at runtime is (near?) impossible, so you are basically forced to implement a new class for each entity and create a new object each time the entity "evolves". That's why I suggest you to go with one of these solutions:

- Use `Map<String, Object>` to store entities' properties. This is a very flexible solution which will allow you easily add and remove "fields" at the cost of losing their type data. Checking if the entity has a certain property will be a cheap `contains` call.
- If you really want to stick to a million custom classes, use interfaces with getters and setters in addition to fields. For example, convert `private String name` to `interface Named { String getName(); void setName(String name); }`. This is much easier to refactor and does not rely on reflection. A class can implement as many interfaces as you want, so this is pretty much like the field solution, except it allows you to create custom getters/setters with extra logic if desperately needed. And determining if entity has a certain property is a `entity instanceof MyInterface` call, which is still cheaper than reflection.

Comment: +1 for mentoining "It implies that you know the field beforehand". Reflection is supposed to be used to analyse programs dynamically of which it is impossible to know any compile time information, like when you are loading a plug-in or something along those lines from a third party.

Comment: Exactly what I was getting ready to say about reflection.  Vic almost certainly should be wrapping the retrieval of various values in a common interface, or using Java 8 method references.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie Thank you very much for your help. I obviously overlooked Maps. Just to mention, my idea was to design several very basic logical blocks (one class for each block) that would compose evolutional changes Lego-like. Not a million classes.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie Being a newbie I was trying to figure out by myself how an `interface` can be used instead of (converted to) a `field` but couldn't do it. Even though you gave a brief example. Could you, please, provide a more detailed example if it's possible? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @Vic I'm not saying that you should drop field usage altogether, I'm just saying that you should define public API by interfaces, not by checking which fields they contain. This is a quick, rough example: http://pastebin.com/DkbieQMH

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie I can see now what you meant. It helped me. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest writing a method that use to get your fields supply it a string and then if the exception is thrown notify whatever needs to be notified that it was not valid and if the exception isn't caught return the field.

Although I do agree with the above that reflection should not be used heavily.

Comment: I disagree. If you're referencing a specific field by name and it turns out to be invalid, there is something wrong with your code. Actually, the only sensible reason one would want to find a field by name is getting the `Unsafe` instance. I saw multiple reflection-based methods in commercial projects I worked on that, for example, allowed quick conversion of objects to collections of strings by using a specific field/getter, but they were extremely error-prone. If you need a specific `Field` instance, I think it's more logical to scan the class for it (for example, by checking annotations).

Comment: I answered based on the question he asked and what I understood from how he asked it. I cannot see the code or how it's being or for what purpose. I know for one I had a college project at some stage based on reflection where I had to be able to look at user input and preform a method or get a field based on that without knowing about any objects on compile time. Probably not the most eloquent solution as I haven't done as much work with reflection since.

Comment: It's a bad example, IMHO. Using a simple `Map<String, T>` is much more efficient, less error-prone and forces you to deal with eventual `null` rather than nasty exception. As **univise** nicely said, "reflection is supposed to be used to analyse programs dynamically", rather than an alternative to interfaces, collections or getters/setters.

Comment: My answer was based off naivety. I don't think mapping them ever dawned on me when writing it originally, I am even tempted to go back and try it. Although I would consider Map <String, Optional<T>> instead for those null values

Comment: Still, when someone tries to use `try-catch` mechanism and throws a *fake* exception to exit a loop prematurely, you don't tell him "reuse the exception object to limit garbage collection and leave the catch block empty, as printing the stack trace is pretty expensive" - you inform him about misusing the API and introduce to `break`, right? Something is most likely wrong with Vic's code, and I don't think that listing workarounds is the way to go.

Comment: BTW, `Map<T, Optional<T>>` doesn't make much sense, since default `Map` implementations still return null if there is no value mapped to a certain key. In order to actually get an empty optional for **any** key, you would have to override some map class (if not present: return empty optional) or map an empty optional to **every** possible key there is. : P